# Use regexes in AOP poincuts?

Tags: java, regex, aop, aspectj

I'm starting on AOP. I want execute `beforeStart()` before each method of MainMenuActivity class that start with "start". Something like this:

```
@Before("call(void " + packaging + "MainMenuActivity.startCrearParte())" +
            " || call(void" + packaging + "MainMenuActivity.startAsignar())" +
            " || call(void" + packaging + "MainMenuActivity.startCargaTrabajo())" +
            " || call(void" + packaging + "MainMenuActivity.startAsignados())" +
            " || call(void" + packaging + "MainMenuActivity.startFinalizadosNoEnv())" +
            " || call(void" + packaging + "MainMenuActivity.startSincronizar())"
    )
    public void beforeStart() {
        //DO SOMETHING
    }
```

Can I use a regular expression? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use wildcards:

```
@Before("call(void " + packaging + "MainMenuActivity.start*())")
```

See http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/released/progguide/semantics-pointcuts.html

Comment: Thanks, it works. Although the concatenation of "packaging" in annotation value doesn't work. I hadn't tried to compile yet.